# ssrs report is being generated but not showing

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Hi when I tried to generae one report in SSRS 2008 R2 (client machine) I'm getting report is being generated message but not showing any report.

[image: SSRS Report Error]

Any Idea? the same report I can able to get in other machines.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check their security settings for the browser and make sure their computer is up to date.  I would try adding the site to the trusted sites list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you said everything is upto date and the same report is working for other inputs. For particular inputs only it is not working in that machine. The same inputs working with other machine is fine. Any clue?